# How to sync CouchDB from multiple PouchDB in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I am working on an angular app. How I can make multiple PouchDB sync to a single CouchDB without any information loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do replication by filter

1. Created filter in CouchDB for every client databases;
2. Start [replication](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) from CouchDB to client by filter (look at replication option named **filter**)
3. Start replication for all documents from client to CouchDB for every client database.

You can find everything you need [here](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) (examples 3, 4)

Answer (score 2):

if you mean by creating multiple PouchDB instances, then you have to create their respective listener to each PouchDB instance pointing to the remote DB you want ( the CouchDB in question ).

this example for the listener worked for me:

```js
var sync = PouchDB.sync('mydb', 'http://localhost:5984/mydb', {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('change', function (info) {
  // handle change
}).on('paused', function (err) {
  // replication paused (e.g. replication up to date, user went offline)
}).on('active', function () {
  // replicate resumed (e.g. new changes replicating, user went back online)
}).on('denied', function (err) {
  // a document failed to replicate (e.g. due to permissions)
}).on('complete', function (info) {
  // handle complete
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: This is correct. You can also sync from multiple PouchDBs into an in-memory PouchDB and then sync from that PouchDB to the server.